# Android: Application cannot access external storages after reinstallation due to invalid UID

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard, storage-access-framework

After uninstallation and reinstallation, our application cannot write to application folder (`<sdcard>/Android/data/<applicationpackage>/files`) on external storages, cannot work with MediaStore provider and cannot access other files on SD card using Storage Access Framework. The issue occurs randomly but it is quite common and it is easy to reproduce on many devices.

It can be reproduced on many Android 5.x devices with SD card:
LG G3 VS985 4G (5.1.1), LG G Pad V500 (5.0.2), Alcatel Idol 3, Nvidia SHIELD Tablet K1 (5.1.1), Verizon SM-G900V (5.0), and other LG, Alcatel, Asus devices...

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install application
2. Create some files in application folder (`<sdcard>/Android/data/<applicationpackage>/files`) on SD card. The UID of this folder is e.g. 10206. Application UID is also 10206. Access to SD card works fine. I can access application folder or access other folders via Storage Access Framework
3. Uninstall application - application folder on SD card is correctly deleted.
4. Re-install application (It has to be completely uninstalled prior reinstallation. By updating the application, you will not reproduce it.)

Now one of these 3 cases can occur:

CASE A) NO BUG: UID of application is increased to e.g. 10207, UID of application folder on SD card is the same - 10207 and everything works fine. I can access application folder or access other folders via Storage Access Framework.

CASE B) BUG: UID of both app and application folder on SD card is not increased and remains 10206 but internally (in system) the UID of this application package is obviously already different. This causes following exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Package <applicationpackage> does not belong to calling UID 10206
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getPersistedUriPermissions(ActivityManagerNative.java:3947)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.getPersistedUriPermissions(ContentResolver.java:1715)

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/file from pid=3322, uid=10206 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:446)
```

After repeaing steps 3. and 4., case C) always occurs. Mostly case C) occurs immediately without case B) and repeating steps 3. a 4.

CASE C) BUG: UID of app is increased to e.g. 10207 but UID of application folder (`<sdcard>/Android/data/<applicationpackage>/files`) remains 10206 and cannot be accessed from application. This causes following exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/<applicationpackage>/files/somefolder/somefile.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
```

Any further uninstallations and reinstallations don't help. UID of application folder remains 10206! and UID of app is (correctly) changed after each re-installation. The only workaround is reboot of device. After reboot, the UID of application folder is updated according application UID. After that, everything works fine till next uninstallation. So now I have to force users to reboot device.

Note:

- I obtain application UID by: `android.os.Process.myUid()`
- I obtain application folder UID by: `Os.stat("<sdcard>/Android/data/<applicationpackage>/files").st_uid`

I am facing this issue for a quite a long time and now I am quite sure that it is somehow related to different UIDs. I don't know how to fix or workaround it nicely.